# Creating Bootable CD from a Folder on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bootable-media

How do I create a bootable CD from a folder on Mac OS X.

I have a set of OS files and I need to burn it on to a CD so that I can Install during boot.

Comment: Do you want to know how to develop a program that does that?

Comment: any built in command line tool like ,disk util, also will do. I want to add it in my program of course.